# how to determine if request object was initiated from web-browser or REST API call?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Our website has django template webpages and API calls that interact with it.

Some of the inner business logic functions have access to the request object and I need an effective way to determine whether it was an API call that initiated it, or a django template as this will affect the data I send back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.request import Request as RESTRequest

def is_rest_request(request):
    return isinstance(request, RESTRequest)
```