# Making my Django Endpoint Restricted so that only I can access it

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, http-get

I'm very new to websites.

I'm trying to process payments using Stripe in a JS file, and this file is static meaning it is public. I'm trying to take the part that makes an API request with a secret key and move it to the backend and then *call* the backend to receive the response that comes from using the secret key.

However, currently any person is able to make the request, which defeats the purpose of what I am doing.

```
def payment(request):
    return render(request, 'interface/about.html')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return(HttpResponse("laterthere"))
```

urls.py

```
    path('payment', views.payment, name="payment")
```

JS:

```
var resp1 = await fetch('https://url.com/payment', {
            method: 'GET'
        });
```

Is there any way to do this? If suggesting a better direction to go in please do provide resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authentication to your API. This way you can assign permissions to users so that only they can access certain login. As an example, imagine you build your `User` model, to have a `is_admin` property (which is default by django). Then you can check if the user is an admin.

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_admin:
        return(HttpResponse("laterthere"))
    else:
        raise AuthenticationError
```

Here is more information for DRF https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: I see how that works generally, but in my case I'm trying to have it authenticate when people are using the website to make a payment, but not authenticate if someone is just making a call to the endpoint. Is that possible? To clarify, I'm not actually signed in when making payments, other people are just on the site (no login is required on the site) and the GET requests it should be valid. But when it's not happening in the website (like if someone runs a script trying to access my endpoint) it shouldn't be valid.

Comment: I understand. I cannot think of an alternative apart from an auth approach. With auth you would use some sort of `Authorisation Header` which is what is going to let your backend know that who is making the request is allowed.
A naive way would be so set some sort of "password" as part of the request body which only you know and validate it on the backend. This is less, less secure and wouldn't recommend, but it depends on what your project needs (e.g. if its only a passion project it may be okay)

Comment: What would be ideal in your case would be something to tell your backend "hey, this request came from a website, not from postman". This is the closest thing I found, perhaps give it a go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276977/how-to-determine-if-request-object-was-initiated-from-web-browser-or-rest-api-ca

Comment: I tried that here but am having an issue. Is that what you meant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72822533/how-to-identify-that-requests-are-coming-from-my-own-django-website

Comment: Yes, its to do with using SSL between the server and client. It's certainly possible.